# Is every theory meeting Gödels incompleteness, also incomplete below its consistency level?

Tags: first-order-logic, incompleteness

Is it always the case that for any theory $T$ that meets Godel's criteria for incompleteness, there is a sentence $P$ such that neither $T \vdash P$, nor $T\vdash \neg P$; and such that $T+P$ is equi-consistent with $T$, and $T+ \neg P$ is equi-consistent with $T$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1975706/462

Comment: Do you want to also require that $T+\neg P$ be equiconsistent with $T$? If not, then $\neg Con(T)$ is an example of such a $P$ (as long as the base theory with respect to which we're *establishing* equiconsistency is strong enough to prove Godel's theorem).

Comment: Yes of course!, I'll add it.